# Python coordinate transformation of shapefiles without GDAL

Tags: python, spyder, shapefile

I have big problems by using GDAL in my Anaconda Spyder, but I need to do the following coordinate transformations:

```
 src_spatialReference = osr.SpatialReference()#input coordinate system
 src_spatialReference.ImportFromEPSG(inputCoordSystem) #import coordinate system from EPSG code

 dst_spatialReference = osr.SpatialReference()#output coordinate system
 dst_spatialReference.ImportFromEPSG(outputCoordSystem) #import coordinate system from EPSG code

 transform_coord = osr.CoordinateTransformation(src_spatialReference,dst_spatialReference) 

#transform geometry object
 geomObj = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(geomObj.wkt) #get geometric Object as WKT (well known text) and transform it to org geoemtry
 geomObj.Transform(transform_coord) #transform object to other coordinate system
 geomObjTransf=shapely.wkt.loads(geomObj.ExportToWkt()) #create shapely object form org geometry objekt
```

Does someone has an idea how to do it without GDAL?

I tried it with `transform` from `shapely` but I read it is only for points and I need to transform shapefiles and it is just for points.

I am using Spyder 3.2.8 in Anaconda and Python 3.6.4

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Combining these two libs might be an option in native python: https://pypi.org/project/pyshp/ and https://github.com/jswhit/pyproj Otherwise, perhaps command line GDAL tools are an option? You could also leverage your python skills by scripting something in QGIS (which uses GDAL under the hood): https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! Can I ask if it possible to run the code I showed in the Python console inside QGIS which is mentioned here: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#run-python-code-when-qgis-starts

Comment: It should be possible. What's the reason you'd like to do it without GDAL? Are you getting an error?

Comment: That would be great, when I'm in the office tomorrow I will check it! Sadly I have the following error and couldn't solve it: ImportError: /home/mattes/anaconda3/envs/gmt-python2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/../../../libgdal.so.20: undefined symbol: _ZN11xercesc_3_211InputSource11setEncodingEPKDs

Comment: Thank you very much for the idea, I tested it and it works! But now I have another problem, how can I transfer the data back to my main program? I tried to use `pickle` but with this, I get the following error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is not the best solution but this one wors for me now:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.geometry import LineString  
from pyproj import Proj, transform

df_all = df

# store the measured points in a list
measuredpoints_list = np.array([df_all.LON20Hz.tolist(), df_all.LAT20Hz.tolist()]).T

# transform them to a proj. coord. system
measuredpoints_listtrans = []
for i in range(len(measuredpoints_list)):
    measuredpoints_listtrans.append(PyProjTransform(4326, 3581, measuredpoints_list[i]))
cl_trans = []
for i in range(len(cl)):
    cl_trans.append(PyProjTransform(4326, 3581, cl[i]))
```

With `shapely` it is possible to transform a shapefile point wise, after that, you can create a new array which contains the transformed points. With this, you can start further calculations.